# Calling a function through require in NW.js

Tags: javascript, require, node-webkit

In my main script:

```
var renderer = require('./templates/renderTemplates.js');

function show(json){
    renderer.render(json);
}
```

and in renderTemplates.js:

```
var render = function(json) {
  console.log(json);
   ...
}
```

Obviously, it says that render can't be called. How do I make a function accessible from another script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply export in renderTemplates.js

```
var render = function(json) {
  console.log(json);
   ...
}
module.exports = {
    render: render
}
```

Then you can use `renderer.render()` as you do in your main script.